# How to programmatically replace a type with another type

Tags: c++

I would like to test the performance of a custom string and map implementation in my code. I would like to replace all objects of types `std::string` and `std::map` with `custom::string` and `custom::map`. Is there a reasonably scriptable way of doing this?

I am more interested in a methodology that would work for any given source and target types. Ideally a method that would also support different API names, i.e. replace `std::map::insert()` with `custom::map::custom_insert()`.

I don't/can't trust a search/replace/regex or any solution that solely depends on textual representation of the types. Providing a tutorial or working example would also be amazing.

Comment: You're asking for a C++ parser and refactoring tool, which is a very tall order. If I were you, especially since this is just for debugging and testing purposes and isn't for anything in production, I'd go with a glorified regex. Simple and dumb, but gets it right most of the time.

Comment: Why don't you trust a search/replace/regex that changes text in source files?   Logic would suggest that an obvious solution is to replace all instances of `std::string` with `custom::string`, `using namespace std` with `using namespace custom`  (and similar for other types you need to replace) would represent a 95%+ solution.  A custom tool would, more than likely, be based on exactly that, even if it is bundled differently and portrayed as if it is something different.

Comment: Just a question. Do you really want to replace text in the source code. Would it be better to use ````using````. Because ````using```` is exactly designed for such cases. And it makes reading easier. You could write ````using String = std::string;```` Or, as the alternative implementation: ````using String = custom::string;````: This will give you maybe more flexibility and ensure that you are using same member functions. Maybe you can consider . . .